# How to get the name list on Realm database and display on my stimulator?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

Here I have a Realm Database which is have some data in it and I want to display it on my Stimulator but it turn out display some other thing. What's wrong in my code?

This is the data of my Realm Database and I also marked the data which I want to display it.

[image]

The stimulator which display something like this.

[image]

And here is my **ViewController.swift** code's.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource  { //UITableViewDataSource

    @IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let realm = try! Realm()
         let theItem = realm.objects(Item.self).filter("itemid >= 1")
         return theItem.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let theItem = realm.objects(Item.self).filter("itemid >= 1")
        print(theItem)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1")
        //I suspect the problem is at here...
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(theItem)"
        return cell!

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}

class Category: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var caid: Int = 0
}

class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var itemid: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var cateid: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: `Item` is my class. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to display the data already. I just need to add `indexPath.row` in my code and it can handle the data already.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let theItem = realm.objects(Item.self).filter("itemid >= 1")
    //I only add below this indexpath
    let cellData = theItem[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1")
    //and change this part and it's done.
    cell?.textLabel?.text = cellData.name
    print(theItem)
    return cell!
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to get the string from the `Item` object. try something like

`"\(theItem.name)"`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I found that I only need to use indexpath.row to handle the array and it's done. I already posted my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getNames() -> [String]{
    let items = realm.objects(Item.self).filter("itemid >= 1").toArray(ofType: Item.self ) as [Item]
    return items.map { $0.name }
}

extension Results {
func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    var array = [T]()
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        if let result = self[i] as? T {
            array.append(result)
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what the point of this code is, however, using it will break the connection between objects and Realm so they will no longer have live updates and will not be observable. Additionally, you don't need an extension to cast the results to an array - this will do it `let itemArray = Array(items)`

Comment: yeah this is true let itemArray = Array(items) can be used to cast result to array